# How to convert a string in format YYYYMMDD to date without string manipulations in a consistent way in AWS redshift and AWS athena

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I'm looking to convert a string into a date in a consistent way in both AWS redshift and AWS athena without string manipulation.

The string that I need to convert into a date is in the format YYYYMMDD.

(I know the format YYYY-MM-DD would be easier to work with, however, I am unable to change the source format).

The only solution that I have currently found that works in both is:

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING('20220101',1,4) || '-' ||SUBSTRING('20220101',5,2) || '-' ||SUBSTRING('20220101',7,2) AS DATE)
```

I.e. manipulating the string into a more useable format from `YYYYMMDD` to `YYYY-MM-DD`, then casting as a date.

However, this feels overcomplicated, and I'm hoping there is a conversion to date function that I have missed.

I have tried a few things, but no luck so far.

For example, in redshift, but neither work in Athena:

```
SELECT '20220101'::DATE
```

or

```
SELECT CAST('20220101' AS DATE)
```

And the closest I can get to in athena is as follows:

```
SELECT CAST(date_parse('20220101','%Y%m%d') AS DATE)
```

This isn't the solution though as `date_parse` isn't available in redshift.

Comment: Can you change how the date is stored? For example, if it is kept as `2022-01-01`, then both databases would understand it without needing to specifically cast it.

Comment: I agree that's the better long-term solution, I'm unsure how easy this would be for the team to change, I'll investigate though, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Athena and Redshift have different SQL flavors (Redshift is based on PostgreSQL and Athena is based on Presto/Trino).

For Redshift use the [`TO_DATE`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_DATE_function.html) function:

```sql
select to_date('20010630', 'YYYYMMDD');
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I tried it, works as expected for redshift, however, it doesn't work for athena unfortunately. Returns the error `INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Failed to tokenize string [Y] at offset [0]`

Comment: @SamGilbert Athena and Redshift have different SQL flavors (Redshift is based on PostgreSQL and Athena is based on Presto/Trino). For Athena you should use `date_parse` as in the question. [`to_date`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/teradata.html?highlight=to_date#to_date) has different format support in Athena.

Comment: I was hoping there was a generic date conversion function that behaves similarly in both that I had missed. For example `CAST(... AS DATE)` if my string had YYYY-MM-DD format ...

Comment: @SamGilbert it seems that SQL standard does not have one (though have not studied it well enough), so it's up for the database to define (custom) parsing functions. Yes, if you have datetime in the "valid" default format for engine then casting would work. The problem - you don't. So you need either manually to convert it (if both engine have the same default)  or just modify the query. Personally I would go with second approach.